# getting an Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am writing a live chat program for a client and I have everything working except retrieving the data from the server. I have it almost licked but now I am getting this error in my jquery function telling uncaught syntax error: unexpected identifier, i have tried several variations of this code but it keeps giving me this issue. Here is the code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <?php
    session_start();
    include 'conection.php';
    include 'function.php';

    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM chatSession WHERE user_name = '$name'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $session = json_encode($row['session_id']);
    /*
    function fetchMessages()
    {
        $get = ("SELECT * FROM chatRoom WHERE session_id = '$session'");
        $hold = mysql_query($get, $con);

        if($hold)
        {
            return mysql_fetch_array($hold);
        }
    }
    */
    if(isset($_GET['submitmsg']))
    {
        $message = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['usermsg']);
        $throw = "INSERT INTO chatRoom(session_id, source, message, timestamp)
                  VALUES('".$_GET['id']."', '".$_GET['source']."', '$message'
                  , UNIX_TIMESTAMP())";

        if (!mysql_query($throw,$con))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }else
        {
            fetchMessages();
        }
    }
    ?>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/chatStyle.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="menu">
            <p class="welcome"><b>Welcome, <?php echo $row['user_name']; ?></b></p>
            <p class="logout"><a href="nameSub.php?logout=true&name=<?php echo $row['user_name']; ?>&id=<?php echo $row['session_id']; ?>">Exit Chat</a></p>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="chatbox">
        </div>
        <form name = "message" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "get">
            <input type = "hidden" name = "name" value = "<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>" />
            <input name = "id" type = "hidden" value = "<?php echo $row['session_id']; ?>" />
            <input name = "source" type = "hidden" value = "<?php echo $row['user_name']; ?>" />
            <input name = "usermsg" type = "text" id = "usermsg" size = "63" />  
            <input name = "submitmsg" type = "submit"  id = "submitmsg" value = "Send" />  
        </form> 
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            fetchMessages = function()
            {
                var sess = <?php echo $session; ?>;
                $.ajax
                ({
                    url:'functions.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:{method:'fetch, sess'},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $('#chatbox').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }

            setInterval(fetchMessages, 5000);
            fetchMessages();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

The problem occurs when I am trying to create the variable sess to pass into the called script so I can then pass it on to the neccessary function to retrieve the data.

ok here is the updated jquery

```
    fetchMessages = function()
    {
        var sess = <?php echo $session; ?>;
        $.ajax
        ({
            url:'functions.php',
            type:'post',
            data:{method:'fetch'},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#chatbox').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

and the functions.php

```
    <?php
    include 'core/conection.php';
    include 'function.php';

    if(isset($_POST['method']) === true && isset($POST['session']) === true && empty($_POST['method']) === false && empty($_POST['session']) === false)
    {
$method = trim($_POST['method']);
$session = trim($_POST['session'];

if($method === 'fetch')
{
    $messages = fetchMessages($session);

    if(empty($messages) === true)
    {
        echo 'A representative will be with you shortly';
    }else
    {
        foreach($messages as $message)
        {
            $ts = $message['timestamp'];
            ?>
            <div class = "message">
            <a href = "#"><?php echo date('n-j-Y h:i:s a', $ts); ?><?php echo $message['username']; ?></a>says:<p><?php echo nl2br($message['message']); ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
    }
```

?>

and finally the fetchMessages()

```
    <?php
    include 'core/conection.php';

    function fetchMessages($session)
    {
        $session = $_GET['$session'];
        $get = ("SELECT * FROM chatRoom WHERE session_id = '$session'");
        $hold = mysql_query($get, $con);

        if($hold)
        {
            return mysql_fetch_array($hold);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I know I have an error somewhere in here because I am still getting no display

newest update jquery code, this displays the session_id as an integer however I still get the unexpected identifier

```
    fetchMessages = function()
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        url:'functions.php',
        type:'post',
        data:{method:'fetch'
              session:'<?php echo $row['session_id']; ?>'},
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#chatbox').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you see which line of your javascript is getting the error?

Comment: Most likely you need quotes: `var sess = "<?php echo $session; ?>";`

Comment: checkout something else: your variable `sess` is not used in your script.

Comment: @dfsq is already json_encoded.

Comment: I feel weird about this line as well `data:{method:'fetch, sess'},`. I know it's not being appended as a query string, but it just looks wrong.

Comment: JSON encoded means it looks like this `{blah blah}`. That is a string encoded in JSON format. Sess needs to be a sting. Also if you are trying to pass it in the data it should be more like: `data: {method: 'fetch', session: sess}`

Comment: @Leeish No JSON encoded means that everything is properly escaped, and no quotes are really needed.

Comment: Well, you might be right, however I think you have another issue, see answer below. I still think you are wrong however.

Comment: i figured out how to get it to stop throwing that particular method however like you said @Leeish it is being passed as a string, how can i pass integers through to jquery so I can pass it on using that method?

Comment: Why not just have the string be converted to an integer after your receive it?  JavaScript has ```parseInt(string)``` available.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @GraficRegret. If the session ID is simple a number, then you could just do `data: {method: "fetch", session: "$row['session_id']"}` I think. No need to encode anything. However all data will be passed to your ajax page gets passed as a string. There is no other way I believe. You must CAST if necessary on the receiving end.

Comment: the session_id is being passed to a second php code that passes it to a third

Comment: See my comments below. You have many "potential" errors. A: You need to pass in the session from the main page through the ajax call to functions.php. B: Your `fetchMessages()` function is incorrectly setting `$session` as it will be a local variable passed in, not in the `$_GET` scope.

Comment: You need a comma `data:{method:'fetch',
              session:'<?php echo $row['session_id']; ?>'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding this as one answer because I believe it's one of your issues. If sess is a JSON encoded string and you want to pass it to the functions php you need:

```
data: {method: 'fetch', session: sess}
```

Or at the least:

```
data: {method: 'fetch, '+sess}
```

Look at your other code in `fetchMessages()`:

```
$session = $_GET['$session'];
```

This is not needed as you are passing in $session to the function. It won't be in the $_GET scope.

Also from `functions.php`:

```
$session = trim($_POST['session'];
```

In your updated javascript you are not even posting anything to session, only to method. You need to add session: 'something' to send it to function.php.

Comment: yeah I caught that and changed it to reflect session_id and I am getting the unexpected identifier again, I even played around with it a bit and got it registering the contents as an integer rather then a string and I still get hit with unexpected identifier. Any ideas? i can post updated code again if you like

Comment: here is the updated code so you can look it over

Comment: 'fetchMessages = function()
    {
     $.ajax
     ({
      url:'functions.php',
      type:'post',
      data:{method:'fetch'
            session:'<?php echo $row['session_id']; ?>'},
      success:function(data)
      {
       $('#chatbox').html(data);
      }
     });
    }`

Comment: ok that doesnt work I will post it as an edit to my orrigional post

Comment: The javascript error should indicate a line where the error occurs in your code. What code is on the line where the error happens?

Comment: the code that displays the session_id

Comment: Data is basically a JSON object so `{key: val, key: val}`. You missed the `,`.

Comment: that's better thanks no more errors on the page.....but I am still not getting anything returned, any ideas? or should I start a new thread for this issue?

Comment: Probably make a new thread focusing on your php code that handles the request. Make sure INDEED your sessionid is getting to your functions.php. If it is and still nothing back, make a new thread about your functions.php items.

Comment: can you give me a suggestion on how to make certain it is making it there?

Comment: on your functions.php just do echo `$_POST['session']; die;` Then something should come back in the data, hopefully whatever `POST['session']` should be. Also, just look in developer tools console when your ajax gets fired. (IE F12, Chrome F12, Firefox download Firebug). You can see the data that gets sent with the call. I always do `alert(data)` in javascript to see the data before I start doing stuff with it to make sure what is coming is what I think is coming.

Comment: thanks I got it echoed out where the code fires for an empty messages return